# You must declare the scalar variable "@ID_PLA" when extracting data from the course

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @ID_PLA INT
SET @ID_PLA = 0

DECLARE Zakaz_cursor1 CURSOR
FOR SELECT ID_PLACEMENT FROM Zakaz


OPEN Zakaz_cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM Zakaz_cursor1 INTO @ID_PLA

PRINT @ID_PLA
```

It is necessary that this code creates a cursor that will contain ID_PLACEMENT. After this cursor, the first line is retrieved and a variable is added, which is then output. However, while executing the command

```
FETCH NEXT FROM Zakaz_cursor1 INTO @ID_PLA
```

I have an error:

```
You must declare a scalar variable "@ID_PLA"
```

I don't understand what's the matter as I declare this variable. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you using a cursor in the first place? From experience, Cursors are almost always used incorrectly.

Comment: The code you have shared would not result in that error.   Please post a script that fully reproduces the error.

Comment: Also, [I can't replicate your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2cdca704f6d37b6ff5e00f358497f0a).

Comment: It seems to be that you execute the code below SET @ID_PLA = 0

Answer (score 0):

This is the right patern for writing a CURSOR-

```
DECLARE @ID_PLA INT

DECLARE Zakaz_cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ID_PLACEMENT FROM Zakaz 

OPEN Zakaz_cursor1  
FETCH NEXT FROM Zakaz_cursor1 INTO @ID_PLA  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

      --Perform your actions here 

      PRINT @ID_PLA

      --END of Actions

      FETCH NEXT FROM Zakaz_cursor1 INTO @ID_PLA
END 

CLOSE Zakaz_cursor1  
DEALLOCATE Zakaz_cursor1
```